# Condition for stopping the gradient descent at local minima

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I have my code for finding the least cost function, but when I am adding the threshold to stop gradient descent at the local minima, am getting below error, can someone help.

> `cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`

```
Input
Math   CS  
92     98
56     68
88     81
70     80
```

code:-

```
def gradient_descent(x,y):
iterations=50
n=len(x)
exponent = -9
m_curr=b_curr=0
learning_rate=0.01
for i in range(iterations):
    y_pred=m_curr*x+b_curr
    cost=(1/n)*sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_pred)])
    md=-(2/n)*sum(x*(y-y_pred))
    bd=-(2/n)*sum(y-y_pred)
    m_curr=m_curr-learning_rate*md
    b_curr=b_curr-learning_rate*bd
    math.isclose(x,y,rel_tol=math.exp(exponent),abs_tol=0.0)
    print("m {},b {},cost {},iteration {},learning_rate {}".format(m_curr,b_curr,cost,i,learning_rate)) x=df['math'] y=df['cs'] gradient_descent(x,y)
```